# Change alternateLink(/edit) to embedLink(/preview)

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-api

As per https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files (files), I hope to use **embedLink** to display a file in web page via IFrame.

embedLink seems to be only available for certain file types, primarily Google Docs format and video; and is of format https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EmwDVqmUBAYcjz/**preview**

alternateLink is always available and is of format https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EmwDVqmUBAYcjz/**edit**

Since embedLink value is not always available, can I replace /edit with /preview and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `alternateLink` when you want to open the file in the appropriate Google viewer. However, it is strongly recommended not to manually construct the URLs.

Instead, you should always retrieve the file metadata and then use the value of the specific field you need. The URL format is not guaranteed, so if you try to guess those links your application may break any time.